# How do I obtain the type/Class of the value inserted into a ContentValues object?

Tags: android, database

My method receives a `Contentvalues` object that is populated with keys and values in another section of my program. Given this `Contentvalues` object, is it possible to find the type/Class of the inserted value for a given key?

If it helps, I know that the type is restricted one among, `Integer`, `Long`, `String` or a `byte[]`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Give this Contentvalues object, is it possible to find the type/Class of the inserted value for a given key?

Not readily. You could call `valueSet()`, iterate to find the value, then check the class of the corresponding value `Object`. I believe this qualifies as "clunky". :-)

Unfortunately, `ContentValues` is final, so there's nothing you can even do by creating your own subclass.

Comment: Thanks. Why would I need to iterate over the result of valueSet()? Wouldn't a plain get("KEY") work?

Comment: @Ya.Perelman: I am a moron. Yes, that would work much better.

Comment: Thanks! Both Log.d("Val Int: ", cv.get("INTVAL").getClass().toString()); Log.d("Val Long: ", cv.get("LONGVAL").getClass().toString()); log the correct classes. But cv.put("BARR", new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}); followed by Log.d("Val BArr: ", cv.get("BARR").getClass().toString()); print "class [B". Why would that be?

Comment: @Ya.Perelman: Because you are getting back `Byte[]`, presumably.